# build failed jenkins iOS no error

Tags: ios, jenkins

I make jenkins job for compilate iOS app but I have a build failed without error :

```
    CodeSign /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXX.com-aevqskpxrxfoyrgrwjxouvdqwsql/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/XXXXX.com.app
    cd /Users/jenkins/workspaceJenkins/XXXXX.com
    setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    Using code signing identity "iPhone Distribution: XXXXXXX (XXXXX)" and provisioning profile "XXXXX-Jenkins" (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
    codesign --force --sign XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --resource-rules=/Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXX.com-aevqskpxrxfoyrgrwjxouvdqwsql/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/XXXXX.com.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXX.com-aevqskpxrxfoyrgrwjxouvdqwsql/Build/Intermediates/XXXXX.com.build/Release-iphoneos/XXXXX.com.build/XXXXX.com.xcent /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXX.com-aevqskpxrxfoyrgrwjxouvdqwsql/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/XXXXX.com.app

Validate /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXX.com-aevqskpxrxfoyrgrwjxouvdqwsql/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/XXXXX.com.app
    cd /Users/jenkins/workspaceJenkins/XXXXX.com
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXX.com-aevqskpxrxfoyrgrwjxouvdqwsql/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/XXXXX.com.app

** BUILD FAILED **

Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I Don't understand I have this error...

Comment: It is possible that the error message occurred earlier in the build. Look back further in the log for error messages and include more of the log in your question.

Comment: I have this for image is not png : Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure. It's possible it's that error ?

Comment: That could be the problem. Why not put that error message in your question.

Comment: Your provisioning profiles are wrong. give correct bundleIdentifier and codeSigning.

Answer (score 5):

when i had the similar  issue

```
Validate /tmp/jenkins/myapp/build/myapp.app
cd /Users/t/Desktop/jenkins/workspace/myapp/Client/myapp
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/user/jdk/bin:/home/user/bin:/home/user/jdk/bin"
setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /tmp/jenkins/myapp/build/myapp.app
```

** BUILD FAILED **

Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure

then i looked back at the log build  and i found that

```
While reading /Users/t/Desktop/jenkins/workspace/myapp/Client/myapp/myapp/media/RatingScreen/Residential_Active@2x.png pngcrush caught libpng error:
```

Not a PNG file..

Could not find file: /tmp/jenkins/myapp/build/myapp.app/Residential_Active@2x.png
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

when i fix this error, it is "BUILD SUCCEEDED"

Comment: I got it two times. in the first time, i deleted it and added again, commited it. it success.  A bit of magic