# build failed react-native 0.6.5 We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, react-native-ios

I'm having this problem "error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening starter.xcodeproj. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details." since I pulled the latest update from the other colleague, I can't run the project in my simulator, but my colleagues side works fine.

- I've tried to change the build system to legacy build system.
- Clone the project again.
- remove the build folder under iOS folder, and run again.
- remove the node module folder and run again.
- I have tested in different device is not working too.

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening starter.xcodeproj. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/nexplatform/Desktop/padini scm mobile/SCM/ios/build/starter

Comment: have you done what the error message states? also, have you searched the net for this common error? and what it means? ans what to do about it? what more information do you get when you run using `--verbose`

Comment: what about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794243/xcode-build-fails-with-error-code-65-without-indicative-message) or other similar posts on stack overflow - have they helped you?

Comment: Yes, I have tried many solutions online but still not working. @JaromandaX

Comment: so, no useful information using `--verbose`

Comment: Here are some of the extra error info might help. @JaromandaX

The following build commands failed:
        CompileC Path/ios/build/starter/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RCTSettings.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTSettings.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTSettingsManager.o RCTSettingsManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Comment: That may be more useful **in the question** so someone who has an apple computer may know better than me :p

Comment: some RTC file are not file

Comment: that's very zen, but has no meaning to me

Comment: @LowLixing1213 have you tried to make a legacy build instead of new build system? I don't know how to do this with cli but in xcode you can change the setting under `File => Project Settings => Build system`

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze yes, I've changed it to legacy build. I've already fixed it by deleting the startProj file and npm install pod, pod install in the ios folder. Thank you guys.

Comment: @JaromandaX I've already fixed it by deleting the startProj file and npm install pod, pod install in the ios folder. Thank you guys

Comment: you can find answer in below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725042/error-failed-to-build-ios-project-we-ran-xcodebuild-command-but-it-exited-wit

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install cocoapods
cd projectfolder/ios
pod install
```

and

```
cd..
react-native run-ios
```